# How to efficiently extract names and emails from a contact list?

Tags: php

I'd like to allow users to paste in a list of *new line* separated contacts and have an array of names and emails generated efficiently.

Let's say the possibilities of the entries are:

```
John, foo@corp.com
foo@corp.com, John
John foo@corp.com
foo@corp.com John
foo@corp.com // will have the [name] key empty
John // will not be considered if there is no email
```

Currently my solution is to `explode` by `\n` then explode by commas then guess where the email and names are. I admit that this is totally unreliable and that's why i'd like to see how others can approach this.

The array i'm trying to come up with is like:

```
array(
 [0] => array(
         [name] => John,
         [email] => foo@corp.com
        )
 [1] => ...
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Quite a large bit of code to think about, but you'd obviously need regex and explode

Comment: what about the possibility of `John,foo@corp.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using explode to split the strings, you may want to look into using a regex split:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

This way you can split the string by space, comma, or both all in one line of code. would probably look something like this:

```
$array = preg_split('#[ |,]+#', $input);
```

Then you can check each field with filter_var() to see which is the email address.

```
filter_var('bob@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

Comment: this way they can seperate their fields with either a space, a comma, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Could try doing it something like this:

1. Read the file line by line (is it a file? Or just a string of text?)
2. Explode by spaces.
3. for each of the array generated from the explode function validate if it's an email address or not (for example, using [this function](https://launchpad.net/isemail)) If its valid then you know it's the email address, otherwise it's the name.
4. You can also then "clean" the name (e.g. remove the ",")

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, here's a general idea I came up with:

1. Search the line for the *last* @ character (in case someone uses a silly name that contains an @ in it, because people like to do that). An email can only contain one @ symbol; if it contained more than one it wouldn't be a valid email.
2. Find the *first space* to the left of the @ symbol. While an email address *may* contain a space, most email servers handle them incorrectly and many email providers forbid spaces from being used in the first place, so it's generally safe to say that no email address will contain a space.
3. Split the string in two on that character (you can simply use `substr()` for this, going from 0 to that character's position, and then that character's position plus one to the end). You will get the first part which is all the name, which may contain a first name, last name, or other information. The second part will be the email address. If there is no space to the left of the @ symbol, then you can imply that no name was given.
4. Trim excess spaces and commas from the beginning and end of both strings (just to be safe).
5. You should validate that the email address part is actually formatted to be an email address using a regular expression.

If you [really] wanted to add support for the space character, you could always look to the character directly left of the @ symbol and if it is a double quote, continue searching left to the second double quote. Email address which contain spaces are wrriten as `"contains a space"@example.com`